# Putting 2 Categories in a file

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
@interface fakeDictionary : NSDictionary
+(NSDictionary *) dictTrivial:(NSString *) ID;
-(NSString *) strIDIfIamTrivial;
@end

@interface fakeDictionaryString : NSString
-(NSDictionary *) dictTrivial;
@end
```

Followed by .m files

```
#import "fakeDictionary.h"

@implementation fakeDictionary

+(NSDictionary *) dictTrivial:(NSString *) ID
{
    NSDictionary * dict = @{@"IDorDefaultSelectorValue" : ID};
    return dict;
}
-(NSString *) strIDIfIamTrivial
{
    return self[@"IDorDefaultSelectorValue"];
}


@end

@implementation fakeDictionaryString

-(NSDictionary *) dictTrivial
{
    NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictTrivial:self]; //I got message that NSDictionary does not support method dictTrivial
}


@end
```

Why I got a message saying that NSDictionary does not support method dictTrivial?  +(NSDictionary *) dictTrivial:(NSString *) ID is clearly declared in fakeDictionary.h

Comment: You've clearly made that a method on `fakeDictionary`, not `NSDictionary`. Neither of your declarations are categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fakeDictionary` is inheriting from `NSDictionary`, it's not a [**Category**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html).

So you should call the method like:

```
NSDictionary * dict = [fakeDictionary dictTrivial:self];
```

Comment: Arrrggghhhhhhhh...............

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's the right way to declare cateogories.

Try:
In .h file

```
@interface NSDictionary(fakeDictionary)
+(NSDictionary *) dictTrivial:(NSString *) ID;
-(NSString *) strIDIfIamTrivial;
@end

@interface NSString(fakeDictionaryString)
-(NSDictionary *) dictTrivial;
@end
```

In .m file:

```
@implementation NSDictionary(fakeDictionary)

+(NSDictionary *) dictTrivial:(NSString *) ID
{
    NSDictionary * dict = @{@"IDorDefaultSelectorValue" : ID};
    return dict;
}
-(NSString *) strIDIfIamTrivial
{
    return self[@"IDorDefaultSelectorValue"];
}


@end

@implementation NSString(fakeDictionaryString)

-(NSDictionary *) dictTrivial
{
    NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictTrivial:self]; //I got message that NSDictionary does not support method dictTrivial
}


@end
```